# How to escape backslash in Powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have a text document with path names and I wanted to delete every "C:\".
I tried using

```
get-content file.txt | %{$_-replace 'C:\', ""}
```

And I got an error that the string was not valid.

Then I tried grave accent:

```
get-content file.txt | %{$_-replace 'C:`\', ""}
```

And also single quotes:

```
get-content file.txt | %{$_-replace "C:'\'", ""}
```

It seems that the "escape" characters of Powershell won't work on this one.

Comment: I tested the first command and it worked for me on Powershell v5?

Comment: Idk it didn't work at all for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no problem whatsover with the forward slash `/`

`\` is a special case with regular expressions (I mean the patterns used by `-match` or `-notmatch` or `-replace`),  use `\\` there to match that character.

```
%{$_-replace 'C:\\', ""}
```

This is because regular expressions use backslash as a special character, for example `\s` means any whitespace character and `\d` means any digit.

Answer (score 3):

To add to kubanczyk's answer, an alternative is to use the Regex Escape [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
%{$_-replace [regex]::Escape("C:\"), ""}
```

This will escape any special characters in the string.

Comment: This will also escape the "." character which some windows calls don't like it being escaped.

Comment: Yeah I know this shouldn't be the answer, when I used it, it just adds a slash in front of any slash that is already there.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the purposes of `Split-Path` with the `-NoQualifer` parameter.

```
PS C:\> "C:\Windows\Notepad.exe" | Split-Path -NoQualifier
\Windows\notepad.exe
```